# Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file:com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn’t exist

Tags: java, appium

After launching the app in the emulator, I tried to locate the objects by `uiautomateviewer`, but when I tried to capture the screenshot it throws the error as

```
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file:com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn’t exist!.
```

I tied with the above steps like stopping the appium and tried to capture the sreen shot via `UIautomatorviewer`. But after stopping the appium server(Ctrl+C from command prompt) automatically the launched app in emulator gets terminated.

So because of this I can’t able to capture the screen shot and identify the obeject values.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you kill the process "node.exe" and enter "adb kill-server" command and then enter "adb devices" and then try locating the element using uiautomator.

Comment: No its not worked

Comment: Can you please attache the screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

kill the adb server and start it again.

sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server